# Git - View Remote branches by creation date

Tags: git

Is it possible to see the list of remote branches by creation date instead of alphabetical order?

Right now i use

```
git branch -r
```

Which outputs the below list of remote branches:

```
 origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
 origin/calendar-view-impl
 origin/containers-redesign
 origin/develop
 origin/dialogs-view-impl
 origin/dropdowns-redesign
```

It would be nice if this could be ordered by CREATION date of the branch.

Comment: I don´t think creation date of a branch is tracked. All you have is commits pointing their parents on the graph. You could not tell a branch pointing to revision xxx created 2 years ago from another branch created 5 minutes ago pointing to the same revision.

Comment: @Edmundo is correct. Branches does not have a creation date attached to them. In fact, a branch is in reality just a small file containing the SHA of the commit it currently points to. This file may have a creation date, but this would be on whatever file system the branch was last pushed to or fetched to, it says nothing about when someone created the branch the first time.

Comment: ahhh ok thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a field in git called authordate which can help to achieve similar result, please try following:

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate'
```

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !

Comment: I didn't need the single quotes around _authordate_

Comment: git for-each-ref --sort=authordate

Comment: Note that this answer reverses the sorting direction with the use of the dash `-` prefix, such that the most recent commit is on top. Point stays that the single quotes are not necessary tho.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the answer given by @sachin-thapa, I have come to the following answer:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-authordate | grep 'refs/remotes/origin/' -m 10
```

This will:

- List only remote branches.
- Sort them by authordate, most recently changed branch on top.
- Limits the result to only 10 results to not get lost in a wall of results.

Now, going the extra mile, you can make an alias for this like below, to make it possible to retrieve this list by just typing `git recent`.

```
git config --global alias.recent '!git for-each-ref --sort=-authordate | grep "refs/remotes/origin/" -m 10'
```